# Simulate curl request with ssl verification in Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, php-curl

I have simulated below curl request with Guzzle in my laraval project. But I recieve 500 error responnse from endpoint. But below curl request returns 200 success with an expected output.

```
$authKey = 'gygyjfdrgrwr334523rf4tgdbdgeg5gd8uiy7ergsetw==';
        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sample.com/endpoint' ,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
                "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
                "scope" => "test"
            ]),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "Authorization: Basic {$authKey}",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ]
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
           CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
           CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
           CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
           CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
           CURLOPT_SSLCERT => "/absolute/path/to/cert/file",
           CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => "passphrase",
        ];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

My Guzzle implementation is as below.

```
$authKey = 'gygyjfdrgrwr334523rf4tgdbdgeg5gd8uiy7ergsetw==';
$response = $this->client->post(
            'https://sample.com/endpoint',
            [
                'body' => http_build_query([
                    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
                    "scope" => 'test'
                ]),
                'debug' => false,
                'config' => [
                    'curl' => [
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
                    ]
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    "Authorization: Basic {$authKey}",
                    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                ],
                'cert' => ["/absolute/path/to/cert/file" , "passphrase"]
            ]
        );
```

Below is the debug information

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 10.111.2.18...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sample.com (11.222.3.44) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=Victoria; L=Melbourne; O=Sample Corporation Limited; OU=Software Engineering Services; CN=sample.com
*  start date: Jun 28 02: 07: 22 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 28 02: 17: 00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "sample.com" matched cert's "sample.com"
*  issuer: C=BM; O=QuoVadis Limited; CN=QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /application/aa/v1/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: sample.com
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.4.1 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.2.15
0: Authorization: Basic gygyjfdrgrwr334523rf4tgdbdgeg5gd8uiy7ergsetw==
1: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 50

* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Sun,
01 Dec 2019 05: 55: 58 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host sample.com left intact
{
    "message": "Server error: `POST https://sample.com/application/aa/v1/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error`
```

Shall I know what I am doing wrong when simulating the curl request in Guzzle?

Comment: Is it possible that cURL accepts a relative path to PEM certificate while Guzzle requires an absolute path?

Comment: @Arcesilas it is absolute path mentioned.

Comment: It is mentioned now, but it was not, hence my question.

Comment: What does it say if you set `debug` to `true`?

Comment: @Arcesilas I added the debug information. Thank you.

Comment: You need to debug the error the server produces when it receives the Guzzle request, compare it with correct behavior when receiving cURL request. Maybe the problem is on the client side (cURL/Guzzle), but you will find out by investigating server side: watch app/server logs.

Comment: @Arcesilas there is no way to debug serverside as it is not accessible. I want to makesure my guzzle implementation is identical to above curl request.

Comment: I understand. There is certainly a difference, but it's really not easy to debug without the server logs. You could try with different parameters until it works. You could try on a server you own. Maybe changing the UserAgent (not sure at all it might be relevant).